# Find the probability that number of items produced in a week is atleast 130

Tags: probability, self-study

Number of Items produced in a factory during a week is a random variable with mean 100 and variance 400. What is the probability that this week's production is atleast 130?

My attempt: using Tchebychev's inequality,
$P(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma)\leq \frac{1}{k^2}$
Hence, $P(X-100\geq 30)\leq \frac{4}{9}$

But the final answer is 1/2. How?

Comment: But still I fail to see how the final answer can somehow be $1/2$. Do you have more details about the distribution of that random variable? Is it possible that we are assuming it's a normal distribution?

Comment: Nothing more. I've stated the original question as such. Then it must possibly be an error in the answer key. Is my answer right?

Comment: Indeed, there is an error in the answer (it cannot be $\frac{1}{2}$ for the reason you stated. And there is also an error in the question, as in cannot be answered in its current form (we can only find a boundary)